# In Kotlin, how can I take the first n elements of an array

Tags: kotlin

In Kotlin, how can I take the first n elements of this array:

```
val allColours = arrayOf(
    Pair(Color.RED, Color.WHITE), 
    Pair(Color.RED, Color.BLACK), 
    Pair(Color.YELLOW, Color.BLACK), 
    Pair(Color.GREEN, Color.WHITE), 
    Pair(Color.BLUE, Color.WHITE), 
    Pair(Color.BLUE, Color.WHITE), 
    Pair(Color.CYAN, Color.BLACK), 
    Pair(Color.WHITE, Color.BLACK))
```

So how can I fill `pegColours` with the first say 3 Pairs?

```
var pegColours: Array<Pair<Color,Color>> = //???
```

I tried `allColours.take` but it gave an error:

> Expecting an element

Comment: Use `allColours.take(3)`

Comment: @Héctor 2* - 0 1 2

Comment: @Morozov No, 3 is correct.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The problem with your code that you create pairs with color constants which are `Int`s (`allColours` has type `Array<Pair<Int, Int>>)`, but you expect `Array<Pair<Color, Color>>`. What you have to do is change type `pegColours` type and use `take`:

```
var pegColours: Array<Pair<Int, Int>> = allColours.take(3).toTypedArray()
```

Also you have to call `toTypedArray()` cause `Array.take` returns `List` rather than `Array`. Or you can change `pegColours` type as following:

```
var pegColours: List<Pair<Int, Int>> = allColours.take(3)
```

Comment: Thanks. It is working this type of small function make our life so easy

Answer (score 66):

You need to specify the number of items you want to take.

```
allColours.take(3)
```

---

For a random number of random indices, you can use the following:

```
val indexes = arrayOf(2, 4, 6)
allColours.filterIndexed { index, s -> indexes.contains(index) }
```

Note that you can write an extension method for this:

```
fun <T> Array<T>.filterByIndices(vararg indices: Int) = filterIndexed { index, _ -> indices.contains(index) }
```

---

Alternatively, if the indices are consecutive, you can use slice:

```
allColours.slice(1..3)
```

Comment: but what if I wanted to take for example the next pairs: 2 4 6 ?

Comment: @Morozov `.filterIndexed { index, _-> index % 2 == 0 && index != 0 }.take(3)`

Comment: Should be `allColours.slice(0..2)`

Answer (score 9):

I know you already proposed the usage of `take`, but **alternatively** ranges and a simple `map` also help to write idiomatic code as shown next:

```
var pegColours = (0 until 3)
    .map { allColours[it] }
    .toTypedArray()
```

Comment: Quite nice actually!

Comment: What's the advantage of this over take? If one is 'taking 3', then why create more code to read and parse. I see value in your example if one truly wants to 'map' the elements to something else. If that's your use case, I'd suggest adding that as a comment, as I'm considering downvoting this answer. It's not wrong, but I would recommend against creating a range, and mapping over doing a 'take' directly.

Answer (score 4):

You are very close :)

```
val allColours = arrayOf("red", "blue", "green")
println(allColours.take(2))
```

Will give you first two elements ["red", "blue"]

You have to specify the number of elements you want to take from the array