# Take next several items from arraylist

Tags: java, kotlin

I wish to take first 10 items from array list, then after some action take 10 more (for inserting it in android view list). Is it possible in kotlin/java?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In Kotlin, how can I take the first n elements of an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48668090/in-kotlin-how-can-i-take-the-first-n-elements-of-an-array)

Comment: And what have you tired so far? please don't hesitate  to show your attempted code.

Comment: How is this question too broad? I agree that the question may have been a bit low effort, but it's certainly not too broad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `chunked` function. It turns the list into a list of chunks with the specified size.

Like this:

```
list.chunked(10)
    .forEach { chunk ->
        // Do your stuff
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In Java, you can use the sublist method to get the elements from the list - by specifying the indexFrom - indexTo
subList(int fromIndex, int toIndex)